# ¿Cómo insertar correctamente una cadena(contiene clausulas Where) en una consulta sql mediante php?

Tags: php, sql

En mi proyecto tengo una función que recibe dos parámetros, uno de ellos es un int `$numseccion`, al inicio de dicha función se prepara una consulta sql para que devuelva el total de registros de una tabla `noticias` , los cuales son discriminados por una  columna en particular quedando así la clausula  `WHERE noticias.seccion`.

El caso es que si la variable `$numseccion == 0`, no tendría que agregar la clausula antes dicha porque significaría que quiero mostrar todos los registros de la tabla `noticias` en cambio si la variable `$numseccion != 0` (podria ser de 1 a 5) si debería agregar a la consulta sql algo como esto  `WHERE noticias.seccion = $numseccion` , si trabajo con `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` de todas maneras nose si mi código es una buena practica de todos modos, esa seria mi primera interrogante y la segunda es que al intentar insertar una cadena dentro de mi consulta, la cual podría o no ser una clausula where dependiendo del valor de `$numseccion`.

Me sale un mensaje de error que se esperaba un parámetro. Este es el mensaje devuelto

> "Warning: mysqli_stmt_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
> bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\observatorio\funciones.php on line 18
> Error: . Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
> bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\observatorio\funciones.php on line 19"

a continuación el fragmento del código de la función.

```
function noticias($numpag, $numseccion)
{
    include("conexion.php");
    $seccion=" ";
    if ($numseccion != 0){
      $seccion=" WHERE noticias.seccion = $numseccion";
    }


    $actualpag = $numpag; /* guarda la pagina actual */
    if($consulcant = mysqli_prepare($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias ?")) /* se consulta mediante sql cuantos registros existen */
    {  
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulcant,'s',$seccion);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($consulcant);
      $resulcant = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulcant);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($consulcant));
      die(mysqli_error($consulcant)); 
    }
    while($arraycant = mysqli_fetch_array($resulcant)){
      $cantreg = $arraycant[0]; /*se guarda la cantidad de registros en la variable cantreg */
      $cantpag = contar_paginas($cantreg); /*medianta la funcion contar_paginas se resuelve en cuantas paginas se dividira las noticias en base a la cantidad de registros*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo puedes enlazar valores, no toda una cadena con filtro, columna y valor, porque, en caso de proporcionar número de sección, la consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias 'WHERE noticias.seccion = 5'
```

Por supuesto, eso genera error y `mysqli_prepare()` devuelve `false` en lugar de un recurso para acceso a resultados.

- Crea una cadena para la consulta
- Agrega el filtro si es necesario
- Prepara la consulta
- Si se proporcionó número de sección, enlaza el parámetro con el tipo que corresponda, `i` es para entero
- Ejecuta la consulta

```
function noticias($numpag, $numseccion)
{
    include("conexion.php");
    // Crear consulta para contar
    $contar = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias';
    // Agregar claúsula WHERE si es necesario
    if ($numseccion != 0){
      $contar .= ' WHERE noticias.seccion = ?';
    }


    $actualpag = $numpag; /* guarda la pagina actual */
    // se consulta mediante sql cuantos registros existen
    if($consulcant = mysqli_prepare($contar))
    {
      // Si hay filtro, enlazar parámetro
      if($numseccion != 0) {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulcant,'i',$numseccion);
      }
      mysqli_stmt_execute($consulcant);
      $resulcant = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulcant);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($consulcant));
      die(mysqli_error($consulcant)); 
    }
    while($arraycant = mysqli_fetch_array($resulcant)){
      $cantreg = $arraycant[0]; /*se guarda la cantidad de registros en la variable cantreg */
      $cantpag = contar_paginas($cantreg); /*medianta la funcion contar_paginas se resuelve en cuantas paginas se dividira las noticias en base a la cantidad de registros*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabia que solo se podía enlazar valores y no cadenas. @Triby

Answer (score 0):

- Mediante una sentencia `if`se compara si la variable `$numseccion == 0` entonces se procede a realizar `mysqli_prepare()` sin enlace de parámetros
- Sino `ELSE` se prepara la consulta con enlazamiento de parámetros, en este caso un entero `i`

,

```
function noticias($numpag, $numseccion){
include("conexion.php");
if ($numseccion == 0){
  if($consulcant = mysqli_prepare($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias")) /* se 
consulta mediante sql cuantos registros existen */
  {  
    mysqli_stmt_execute($consulcant);
    $resulcant = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulcant);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($consulcant));
    die(mysqli_error($consulcant)); 
  }
}
else{
  if($consulcant = mysqli_prepare($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias WHERE noticias.seccion = ?")) /* se consulta mediante sql cuantos registros existen */
  {  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulcant,'i',$numseccion);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($consulcant);
    $resulcant = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulcant);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($consulcant));
    die(mysqli_error($consulcant)); 
  }
}

$actualpag = $numpag; /* guarda la pagina actual */


while($arraycant = mysqli_fetch_array($resulcant)){
  $cantreg = $arraycant[0]; /*se guarda la cantidad de registros en la variable cantreg */
  $cantpag = contar_paginas($cantreg); /*medianta la funcion contar_paginas se resuelve en cuantas paginas se dividira las noticias en base a la cantidad de registros*/
}
```